# CakePHP 2.x Custom Route Pagination

Tags: cakephp, routes, pagination

I have a the following custom route (which works fine):

```
Router::connect('/:city', array('controller' => 'dealers', 'action' => 'index'), array('city' => '[a-z]+'));
```

With this route, I am trying to get paginated pages 2, 3, …:

```
Router::connect('/:city/:id', array('controller' => 'dealers', 'action' => 'index'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('city', 'id'),
        'city' => '[a-z]+',
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
        )
);
```

The **first problem** now is, that if I enter *domain.com/washington/2* it doesn't pass the id to Pagination and I still get page 1.

The **second problem** is that I do not get the Pagination Helper to write the above link. If I try this in my view:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array
    ('url'=> array(
        $city[0]['City']['url'],
        $this->params['id']
        )
    )
);
```

It still gives me:

*http://domain.com/dealers/index/washington/page:2*

I apologize in advance if this is a no brainer, but I am new to this and couldn't figure it out with the available questions/answers here, or the docs.

**UPDATE 1:**

I now tried the following for *domain.com/washington/page/2* , but it just routes to pagination page 1:

```
Router::connect('/:city/:slug/:id', 
    array('controller' => 'dealers', 'action' => 'index'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('city', 'slug', 'id'),
        'city' => '[a-z]+',
        'slug' => '[a-z]+',
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
        )
);
```

In the action I am doing this:

```
public function index($slug = null, $id = null) {some code}
```

In the view I added:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

Still no luck, I'd be very very glad if someone could help out!

Comment: Make sure you arent restricting it using `Router::connectNamed()`

Comment: I found my solution in your problem., Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the url *domain.com/washington/page/2* to work by adding this to AppController (beforeFilter):

```
if (isset($this->request->params['page'])) {
 $this->request->params['named']['page'] = $this->request->params['page'];
}
```

And by adding this route:

```
Router::connect('/:city/page/:page', 
    array('controller' => 'dealers', 'action' => 'index'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('city', 'page'),
        'city' => '[a-z]+',
        'page' => '[0-9]+'
        )
);
```

However I do not really understand what happens here, and if this is a good way of doing it. If someone could briefly explain, I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above :)

Also, you may be wanting to use this:

```php
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

This will essentially pass the arguments from the URL to the paginator helper.