# How to maintain a variable in the url which is customized in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

What im trying to do here is  maintain the variable 42 all throughout all pagination urls. I want my url to change from this

```
/exams/take/42/page:2
```

to this

```
/exams/take/42/items/2
```

Again,the number 42  is the variable..and the number 2 is the page number..Thanks.

UPDATE :

```
routes.php
 Router::connect('/examinations/take/:id/page/:page', 
array('controller' => 'examinations', 'action' => 'take'),
array(
    'pass' => array('id', 'page'),
    'id' => '[0-9]+',
    'page' => '[0-9]+'
    )
);
```

in the view/take

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs));
```

AppController.php

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    if (isset($this->request->params['page'])) {
        $this->request->params['named']['page'] =                           $this->request->params['page']; 
    }
}
```

ive tried this ..but the generated url is the same,/examinations/take/42/page:2 ,when i click the next and prev links..

Answer (score 2):

You've to define custom routes:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Example as below:

```
    Router::connect(
      '/exams/take/:id/items/:number',
      array('controller' => 'exams', 'action' => 'take'),
      array('pass' => array('id', 'number'))
    );
```

Also you can get more information from below url try this:
http://www.sakic.net/blog/changing-cakephp-pagination-urls

Comment: Did you tried above my code please let me know it is working for you ?
Glad to assist to you more...

Comment: yes ive tried it..and it generates the url exams/take/42/page:2.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it with the use of custom routing. for more undrestanding you can see cakephp manual to manage custom routing in pagination

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

below will be your

e.g.

And by adding this route:

```
Router::connect('/:id/page/:page', 
    array('controller' => 'examinations', 'action' => 'take'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('id', 'page'),
        'id' => '[0-9]+',
        'page' => '[0-9]+'
        )
);
```

and i does not work you can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917784/cakephp-2-x-custom-route-pagination)

Comment: it does not return the url that i want.The generated url is this     /exams/take/42/page:2. What i want is this, /examinations/take/42/items/2

Comment: i have updated my answer pls try and let me know. is it useful to you

Comment: have you refer link i have given in my answer. that will sure help you to make custom routing. please understand carefully to do that

Comment: shall i include this code also?               $this->Paginator->options(array
    ('url'=> array(
        $city[0]['City']['url'],
        $this->params['id']
        )
    )
);

Comment: welcome, @user2356747 is your problem is resolved ? please accept my answer if i could help you ? i would be appreciate.

Comment: is your question contain answer. ?